# Does ACL override Dir permissions

Tags: linux, access-control-list

Will ACL adds override existing group permissions?   We added rx to a directory tree for group myusergroup with the command blow.

```
setfacl -Rm "g:myusergroup:rx" /opt/oracle/admin'
setfacl -Rdm "g:myusergroup:rx" /opt/oracle/admin'
```

But any user in group dba does NOT have write permissions in newly created directories even though directories show 775 permissions, the effective permission for group is not.

What am I missing?

```
$ ls -ld my_backup

drwxrwxr-x+ 2 oracle dba 4096 Apr 21 08:44 my_backup

$ getfacl my_backup

file: my_backup
owner: oracle
group: dba
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:edmuser:r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:myusergroup:r-x
default:mask::r-x
default:other::r-x

$ touch ./my_backup/test.txt
touch: cannot touch `./my_backup/test.txt': Permission denied

$ id
uid=4000(exagrid) gid=40000(dba) groups=40000(dba)
```

(edit: reformatted)

Comment: Hrm, I am not great with ACLs, but I believe `group::r-x` and `default:group::r-x` are the problem.

Comment: Suggest rephrasing the question to reflect your end goal.  "How do I use setfacl to allow two groups access to a folder and its contents?"  Zoredache is right, the ACL permissions are basically 555.

Comment: @Zoredache is correct.  No group write permission.

Comment: so ACL ***does*** override dir permissions :o

Answer (score 3):

**Introduction**

I don't think the question is best framed in terms of "overriding". An understanding of how traditional file permissions (user/group/other classes) and the more granular access permissions provided by ACLs work together is preferable. James already provided a solution. I'm going to expand on why it works.

---

**Understanding ACLs**

1. Firstly, a default ACL applies not to the directory on which it is set, but to files and subdirectories created within it. The latter files and directories inherit default ACL settings as their own access ACL settings. Thus, the default ACL settings listed are irrelevant to this problem and I won't discuss default ACLs in what follows.
2. In the context of traditional file permission a file has an Owner, a Group, and an Other class – one for each class of user. The permissions set on those classes become the effective permissions of the owning user, owning group, and other user, respectively. If ACLs are supported and used, those class permissions remains the effective permissions of the owing user and other user. By contrast, the Group class permissions now reflect the maximum allowable permissions for any named users or groups (i.e. any users or groups assigned permissions via an ACL entry) (in addition to the owning group). The "Group User" may now be thought of as comprised of the owning group *and* any users or groups assigned permissions via an ACL entry. This means that applications that do not recognise ACLs can still interact with the file.
3. The aforementioned "maximum allowable permissions" value is the ACL mask value. When an ACL entry is made, an ACL mask entry is created. The mask entry has a value that is recalculated following any subsequent ACL modification or `chmod` operation. Recall that the owner group and all ACL named user and group entities *together* make up the Group now. The mask is a response to the inability to represent these *various* permissions with a single permission: it represents a maximum, not a permission shared by all components of the group. In this way, a named user can have greater permissions than the owner group has. Each ACL named entity has "masked permissions", meaning that those of their defined permissions that do not conflict with the maximum set by the mask become their effective permissions. If the mask entry value is `rwx` and a named user's permissions are `rw`, that user's effective permissions are `rw`. On the other hand, if the mask entry value is `r` and a named user's permissions are `rwx`, that user's effective permissions are `r`. To understand why this doesn't cause more problems than it is worth, recall that the mask is recalculated followed each modification.

---

**Addressing the Problem; and the Solution**

It should now be clear that the permissions found in the long-listing

`drwxrwxr-x+ 2 oracle dba 4096 Apr 21 08:44 my_backup`

derive from the ALC's `mask::rwx` setting. The Group permissions value represents the *maximum* permissions for the owning group (dba), in addition to any ACL named entities. John's problem is that the effective permissions of his dba group are defined as `group::r-x`. These permissions are not curtailed by the mask since they don't exceed the defined maximum; but neither are they escalated by the mask.  As James says, the solution is to edit the ACL group permissions.

---

**References**

This answer is from pieced-together personal notes, which don't include citations. Luckily they did include a single link, which following a glance seem to have provided a lot of the content. [POSIX Access Control Lists on Linux, Andreas Grünbacher](https://web.archive.org/web/20191227122558/http://www.vanemery.com:80/Linux/ACL/POSIX_ACL_on_Linux.html)

Comment: Welcome to Stack, this is an excellent first post. Look forward to many more.

Answer (score 1):

So even though ls -ld shows group dba should have write permission on dir my_backup

```
 drwxrwxr-x+ 2 oracle dba 4096 Apr 21 08:44 my_backup
```

The ACL is overriding this.  So if you want to keep write access for dba, you need add that to your ACL group permissions.